# Prove equinumerosity between $2^\mathbb{N}$ and R total orderings

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

T=$\left\{R\vert R \text{ is a total order over } \mathbb{N}\right\}$ 
Prove that T and $2^\mathbb{N}$ are equinumerous.

Comment: Questions have question marks.

Comment: (@AsafKaragila Don't know why, but I thought that the intention was to count isomorphism classes. Pretty sure that version is also a duplicate, though..)

Comment: @Andres: Yeah, that should have an answer somewhere also. But in any case, the single line here says "total order", rather than "modulo isomorphism"...